# Traducir texto al click de botón en idioma por dector del móvil

Tags: android

Llevo unas semanas con JAVA y ANDROID STUDIO, los 2 al mismo tiempo. Tengo como 4 vidas por delante para aprender, pero poco a poco...

Os planteo una pregunta que seguro es muy sencilla:

Quiero introducir un texto, un al pulsar un botón, traducirlo al idioma por defecto del dispositivo móvil. ¿Qué clase o API o lo que sea tengo que usar para traducir? Lo otro sé hacerlo, el texto y el botón y eso.

No pretendo que me lo resuelvan, pero una ayudita para ver por dónde tirar. Voy poniéndome retos pequeños, y este no consigo resolverlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Juan Ma, te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta.

Comment: Puedes usar https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/ Translation API

Answer (score 0):

Como dices que solo quieres una ayuda, esto es lo que se me ocurre:

Primero, tenemos que obtener el idioma del dispositivo. Para esto podemos basarnos en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389640/4520961) de StackOverflow en inglés:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Luego, al pulsar el botón tendremos que mandar el texto mediante una API. Para esto podemos utilizar la API de Google que solo pide el **Texto de entrada** y el **Idioma de Salida**. Puedes encontrar más información en [este enlace](https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api). La llamada sería algo así:

```
"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=" + idiomaSalida + "&dt=t&q=" + texto;
```

Esto sería en terminos más generales. Espero que te sirva para poder lograr tu objetivo. Saludos!

EDIT: Mira [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/JCAguilera/qt5rcz9f) que hice usando javascript.

Comment: Genial. Ya te digo si me sirve. Voy a ver si lo consigo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira el ejemplo que puse para que veas mejor como funciona la API.

Answer (score -1):

pues Locale está casi solucionado.
Ya tengo un objeto declarado y funcionando. "lg", es el ID de la casilla de texto donde vuelco el valor de lenguaje por defecto:

Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
lg.setText(l.getDisplayLanguage());

Hasta donde he llegado, declaro un objeto y lo puedo usar con algo así:

Locale l=new Locale();

Tengo que estudiar cómo es esto de Locale.getDefault();, pero bueno, ya funciona.
Seguiré estudiando porque el tema de la API lo veo más complicado por ahora. Pensé que sería una clase de Android, al ser un producto de Google. Creo que es así, pero si pagas no?

Mientras estudio, una pregunta: si uso mi cuenta de usuario para conseguir una KEY válida para que funcione la API, ¿qué pasaría si cuelgo la APP en Google, qué al traducir cualquiera, lo haría en nombre de mi cuenta?

Gracias.